# Keep Getting Error When Trying to Run Javafx on Eclipse with Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, javafx, module

So I keep getting this error when trying to run my program:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

I'm using a mac with eclipse, and my VM argument is:
--module-path /Users/myname/Desktop/javafx-sdk-11.0.2_3/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

I've tried everything, javafx.controls.jar and the other .jar file are in my lib folder.  I've reinstalled the javafx program, changed my file path around hundreds of times, and I've tried to install plugins.  Does anyone have any idea as too what can be happening?  JavaFX is also an added library in my project, and all the .jar files assocated with it are added to it.  Please let me know if anyone has an idea.  Best!

Answer (score 0):

I had success with the following additional step.

In the *Run Configuration->Dependencies* tab, click the "ModulePath" and then add the JavaFX JDK's jars (or the `/lib` folder that holds the jars) to the list.

You can inspect the generated command line, and check that these are included in the **-p** option.

IDK why this step should be needed. I would think Eclipse should be smart enough to include something on the dependency module path if it were in the project's *Build Path Library* list.

I have questions about this at eclipse.org and gluon. Maybe there will be an explanation, or fix so that this step isn't needed, or an edit to the documentation to let us know we need to do this.